# After update to Drush 7 still version 6

Tags: drush, updating

Running on Debian I have updated Drush to version 7:

composer global require drush/drush:7.*

composer global update

But the command 'drush --version' still tells me:
Drush Version : 6.2.0

I have looked everywhere but didn't find a solution.

Thanx for any help.

Comment: you can add alias of your new drush, do this `vim ~/.bashrc`  

add this line

`alias drush='path/to/your/new/drush/'`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the old version of Drush is still in your $PATH, and comes before the new version.

The [Drush installation instructions](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) says:

`Now add Drush to your system path by placing export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" into your ~/.bash_profile (Mac OS users) or into your ~/.bashrc (Linux users).`

What it does not mention is that changes to your .bashrc file are not immediately reflected in your running system.  You need do one of:

1. Restart.
2. Close and re-open all of your terminal windows.
3. Type `source ~/.bashrc` in all of your open terminal windows.

(Listed in order from easiest and most disruptive, to more work but less disruptive.)  Substitute .bash_profile in place of .bashrc if you made your modification there.